# KOMA-Script typearea and DIV

Tags: margins, koma-script

I was going through the [`KOMA-script Documentation`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) and I found on page 32 a nice table with the `type area` according to the number of `DIV` you set up your document.

[image]

Now, I **MUST** be doing something wrong, because when I set my MWE with different `DIV` values, I get different `\textheight` and `\textwidth` than the one in the KOMA documentation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,BCOR=0mm,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\printinunitsof{mm}{\pagevalues}

\verb|\marginparwidth|: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\marginparwidth}

\pagediagram
\end{document}
```

[image]

Furthermore, I took the trouble to print the pages and then measure the distances.  None of them seem to agree (some of them are off for a couple of mm, other are off by way more).

So, my questions are:

1. How did the guys from the KOMA script documentation arrived to these values shown above?
2. If they did it right (which I'm positive they did), why this doesn't hold true on the printed version?
3. Why are the values I obtained from the `layouts` package is not consistent with the KOMA documentation ---or the printed version, for that matter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Horizontal values

The idea of KOMA-Script is:
If there are two pages side by side, then the white space at the left of the left page (even numbered) is the same as the white space at the right of the right page (odd numbered) *and* is the same as the white space between the text body of the left page and the text of the right page.

With `DIV=12`, the outer margins get 2 units, the inner margins get 1 unit (because they sum up to 2 units from the even and odd page), the text width
gets 9 units:

```
unit width:   210mm / 12 =  17.5mm
outer margin: 2 * 17.5mm =  35mm
inner margin: 1 * 17.5mm =  17.5mm
text width:   9 * 17.5mm = 157.5mm
```

Thus the table values for the text width and inner margin are correct.

**Text width**

The value for `\textwidth` is correct, the table says `157,50mm` and you get `157.49817mm`. (The English version should have replaced the comma by a period for the decimal separator.

**Left margins**

The left margin of an **odd** numbered page is an inner margin and should be 17.5mm:

```
25.4mm     (TeX origin)
-7.89989mm (\oddsidemargin)
----------
17.50011mm
```

Correct (modulo rounding error)

The left margin of an **even** numbered page is an outer margin and should be 35mm:

```
25.4mm     (TeX origin)
 9.59988mm (\evensidemargin)
----------
34.99988mm
```

Correct (modulo rounding error)

### Vertical values

`DIV=12` means that the page height is divided into 12 units. The top margin is one unit, the bottom gets two units and the remaining 9 units go to the text height.

```
unit height:   297mm / 12  =  24.75mm
top margin:    1 * 24.75mm =  24.75mm
bottom margin: 2 * 24.75mm =  49.5mm
text height:   9 * 24.75mm = 222.75mm
```

Therefore the table values for the text height and the top margin are correct.

**Top margin**

Table value: 24,75mm

```
 25.4mm     (TeX origin)
-13.79442mm (\topmargin)
  5.97475mm (\headheight)
  7.1697mm  (\headsep)
------------
 24.75mm
```

Correct.

**Text height**

The table caption is not correctly translated, the German version also says, that `\topskip` is not taken into account.

`\@typearea` calculates the text height the following way:

```
RealTextHeight = topskip + n * baselineskip
with
    n is a natural number
and
    0 ≤ RealTextHeight - DivTextHeight < baselineskip
```

Thus the real text height depends on the value calculated via the div method, the setting of `\topskip` (depends on font size) and `\baselineskip` (also depends on font size).

Therefore the text height can be larger than the table value. The visual text height can even be larger, because the depth of the bottom box on the text area can descend up to `\maxdepth` (= `.5\topskip` with `typearea`) below the text area.

The values for class option `11pt` (default):

```
\topskip:      11pt   ≈ 3.86606mm
\baselineskip: 13.6pt ≈ 4.77985mm
\maxdepth:      5.5pt ≈ 1.93303mm
```

Then

```
\textheight = \topskip   + 46 * \baselineskip
636.60028pt = 11pt       + 46 * 13.6pt         (modulo rounding error)
223.73679mm = 3.86606mm  + 46 * 4.77985mm      (modulo rounding error)
```

and

```
223.73679mm ≥ 222.75mm
223.73679mm < \topskip + 47 * \baselineskip
```

Therefore the text height is correct according to the algorithm used by `\typearea`.

Answer (score 2):

But the values your LaTeX document produces and the values from the table do agree. I don't see a problem. `\textwidth`, `\textheight`, and `\topmargin` are almost as predicted. And the inner margin, which is `1in + \oddsidemargin` on odd pages, is `25.4 - 7.9 = 17.5mm` and thus also as predicted.

For an even page, the inner margin is `\paperwidth - 1in - \evensidemargin - \textwidth = 210 - 25.4 - 9.6 - 157.5 = 17.5mm`. Again, as predicted by the table.

So I really don't see a problem.

Now if you print it, then Adobe Reader may add additional margins as it actually scales down the page unless you chose the right option in the print dialog. So I would expect that margins grow and widths and heights shrink. Make sure you chose the "Actual Size" option when printing. Your printer may not be very accurate too. So margins may increase/decrease my a few millimeters. But I would anticipate that widths and heights should be accurate for most printers, unless you chose the wrong print option in Adobe Reader.